# readout data- atribute with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I whant to write Links in the data atribute and to save up code lines I whant to create the links with a standart text and the href of course with js/jquery

```
var mdUrl = $(".md")this.data('md');
    $(this).html("YES click <a href='" + mdUrl + "'>here</a>");
```

Comment: $(".md")this is wrong syntax

Comment: i know... maybe you could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it right, you want sth like this

```
<div class="md" data="coolsite.com">content.</div>
```

converted to:

```
<div class="md">content <a href="coolsite.com">click here</a></div>
```

You could do this with the following js:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
mds=document.getElementsByClassName("md");
 mds.forEach(function(md){
   md.innerHTML=md.innerHTML+"<a href='"+md.data+"'> click here</a>";
 });
 };
 </script>
```

This loops trough the elements with the "md" class and adds a link to their inner html

Comment: yeah thats what I whant (I would only had used data-md="" but who cares) but it dose not work :/

Comment: @Hisfantor : oh sorry , my mistake. Replaced body with window

Comment: $(".md").each(function(){
        var mdUrl = $(this).data('md');
        $(this).html("<a href='" + mdUrl + "'>content");
    });

this also works :)